# REPO Db type which works with SQL Server as well as SQLite

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

I have an application that supports two databases. MSSQL and SQLite. I am revamping the underlying data access and models and using RepoDb. I would be using the same model for the SQLite and MSSQL. Depending on the connection string I create my connection object (i.e. SQLiteConnection or SqlConnection). I am facing a problem with one of my entities. The problem is with a column type.

```
public class PLANT 
{    
    public string OP_ID {get;set;}
}
```

The `OP_ID` in the SQL Server maps to a uniqueidentifier, and in SQLite to nvarchar. Where I try to do it, it works fine with SQLiteConnection. The problem I face is when I use SqlConnection

```
 var plant = connection.Query<PLANT>(e => e.PL_ID == "3FFA25B5-4DF5-4216-846C-2C9F58B7DD90").FirstOrDefault();
```

I get error

> “No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.Guid' and 'System.String “

I have tried using the `IPropertyHandler<Guid, string>` on the `OP_ID`; it works for SqlConnection but fails for SQLiteConnection.

Is there a way that I can use the same model for both connections?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you share the models between multiple databases if the PK is on the same type, otherwise you will be ending up some coerce problem like this due to the fact that one DB does not support that target type (i.e. `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`).

In anyway, a PropertyHandler is a not way for this as the input types is different. You can use separate models for your SQLite and SqlServer, otherwise, you can explicitly set the `RepoDb.Converter.ConversionType = Automatic` so the coerce will automatically be handled.

I am not recommending the `CoversionType` to Automatic as it is an additional conversion logic on top of data extraction. But that would fix it.